# What does it mean if test accuracy is fluctuating too much on the same data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am running the basic classification code available in tensor flow tutorial for my own dataset, and sometimes I get test accuracy of 1.0 and sometimes it is 0. So I can't understand how can the results be so extreme when I am literally not changing anything. I am just compiling the same python code multiple times

```
import scipy.io

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

mat1 = scipy.io.loadmat('matlab7.mat');
mat2 =  scipy.io.loadmat('matlab8.mat');

Training = mat1['Training7'];
Testing = mat2['Testing8'];
Class_Training = mat2['Class_Training8'];
Class_Testing = mat2['Class_Testing8'];


Training = np.ascontiguousarray(Training.T) ;
Testing = np.ascontiguousarray(Testing.T) ;

model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(14, 98)),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])


model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(Training, Class_Training, epochs=100)


test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(Testing, Class_Testing)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

[Some of the data from the training sete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtSb2.png)

Comment: Please share a code snippet and an example from the dataset, otherwise it's very hard to help.

Comment: @AgostBiro Done

Answer (score 1):

You should check two things: Is your data loaded correctly? Is your network working correctly?

To check whether your data has loaded correctly, you should print a few examples examples and compare them with your spreadsheets. You should also make sure that there are no NaNs in your data. You can do this with numpy: `np.any(np.is_nan(array))` will return true if the array has a NaN value.

To check whether your network is working correctly, you should test it with a toy dataset. The code example below trains the network to distinguish between vectors sampled from a uniform and a normal distribution. The model should be able to overfit the training data perfectly after 100 epochs and it should have a very high test accuracy (I got 0.96). Note that the code sets TensorFlow random seed in the beginning to make sure that the weights are always initialized the same way.

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as k

# Make sure weight initialization is always the same
tf.set_random_seed(0)

n_train = 100
n_test = 50
n_dim = 10
train_size = (n_train, n_dim)
test_size = (n_test, n_dim)
rand = np.random.RandomState(2)

# The training data consists of vectors sampled from a uniform distribution 
# (label 0) and vectors sampled from a normal distribution (label 1).
X_train = np.concatenate([rand.uniform(size=train_size), rand.normal(size=train_size)])
Y_train = np.concatenate([np.zeros((n_train, 1)), np.ones((n_train, 1))])
X_test = np.concatenate([rand.uniform(size=test_size), rand.normal(size=test_size)])
Y_test = np.concatenate([np.zeros((n_test, 1)), np.ones((n_test, 1))])                    

model = k.Sequential([
    k.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(n_dim,)),
    k.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    k.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Hope this helps!